# How to install Iron-Python in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, ironpython

While running an empty iron-python forms application. I'm getting following error:

> The environment ironpython 2.7-32 appears to be incorrectly configured or missing

I've searched a lot and ran into this solution: [Visual Studio - "The environment ironpython 2.7-32 appears to be incorrectly configured or missing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045103).

I have downloaded iron-python from GitHub but I am not sure how to install it.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you download IronPython from [here](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/releases/tag/ipy-2.7.9), it should have a .msi file. Just install it like a regular installer. Once that is done, check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#creating-an-environment-for-an-existing-interpreter) for setting up the environments.

Answer (score 2):

Please download and install the [IronPython 2.7.9](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/releases/tag/ipy-2.7.9), then reopen the VS 2017, it should works like the following:
[image]

Comment: I think you missed my question. I have downloaded iron-python package but don't know how to install it.

Comment: I think you can just click on the msi file and follow the dialog to install it, like you would with any app.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2019-no-longer-have-ironpython-wpf-a/1423202) on https://visualstudio.com, Visual Studio no longer supports IronPython.