# Windows Forms in Visual Studio with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, winforms, ironpython

Steps to reproduce:

1. I created a new project in Visual Studio
2. Selected Python > Desktop > "IronPython Windows Forms Application"

However, as soon as I open the project I encountered several errors which I don't know how to solve. The errors are unresolved import clr an similar.

[image: Brand New Windows Forms Python Project]

Comment: Can you include the full text of the error message you're getting?

Comment: Yes. The full text error says "unresolved import clr", "unresolved import System.Drawing", "unresolved import System.Windows.Forms".

Comment: Did the steps I listed below help solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting the following error `unable to resolve 'clr'`:

[image: Example Error]

It's likely that you don't have a python interpreter *installed* or *configured* for Visual Studio

Per the question [The environment ironpython 2.7-32 appears to be incorrectly configured or missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46045103/1366033)

> The Visual Studio Installer does *not* include an IronPython Package option to install

So you need to:

1. [Download IronPython from Github](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/releases/) and install it
2. Then, select the correct [Python environment within your VS project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#the-python-environments-window).

Comment: Hi KyleMit, sorry for haven't given you an answer sooner. Lot of work and family affairs ... I've installed the IronPython Package and also selected the 3.7 64 bit Python environment but the warnings still appear. It's very surprising this happens. I believe it might be something related to he .NET framework as they are .NET assemblies. Thank you very much for your help.